# What is the proper way to have an asychronous python script wait for a response from a server?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I currently have a program that does work on a large set of data, at one point in the process it sends the data to a server for more work to be done, then my program looks for the completed data periodically, sleeping if it is not ready and repeating until it fetches the data, then continuing to do work locally.

Instead of polling repeatedly until the external server has finished, it has the ability to send a simple http post to an address I designate once the work has finished.

So I assume I need flask running at an address that can receive the notification, but I'm unsure of the best way to incorporate flask into the original program. I am thinking just to split my program into 2 parts.

part1.py

does work --> send to external server

part1 ends

flask server.py
receives data --> spawns part2.py with received data

The original program uses multiprocessing pools to offset waiting for the server responses, but with using flask, can I just repeatedly spawn new instances of part2 to do work on the data as it is received?

Am I doing this all completely wrong, I've just put this together with some googling and feel out of my depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use broker with a message queue implemented ex. Celery + Redis or RabbitMQ. Then, when the other server finishes doing whatever it has to do with the data it can produce an event, and the first server will receive a notification.

Comment: I edited my question as I think it was unclear, the external server can only give an http post to some url, so I think I can't use these solutions right?

Comment: Yes, you can't. But what you can do, is to add Flask to the original program, throw away multiprocessing pools and use asyncio instead. After the external server finishes the job, it should send POST request to the original server and the Flask handler should use asyncio (again) to resume the original process.